# Inductive and Capacitive couplers in power line carrier communication?

Tags: power-line-communication

I have searched a lot in internet for getting simple circuit diagrams of Power line couplers (both inductive and capacitive) which I am supposed to explain to my students. Also our college library doesn't have books on the subject of power line communication. So I would be grateful if someone can help me with the circuit diagrams and working principle of inductive and capacitive couplers which couple information to and from power line cables. Or at least please mention any good website links or other internet resources.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is going to be from the applications notes of manufacturers who sell chipsets into  this market. Like Maxim semi, ST, Analog devices, Avago, NXP etc.

Comment: While useful, a response of this form might be better as a comment than as an answer, since it seems to be encouraging manufacturers you didn't mention to post links to their sites as well.